# Series is not updating in Apexchart for Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, series, pie-chart, apexcharts

I am trying to make a piechart for a data record that contains a financial plan for students (rent, tuition, food, etc.) to help them visualize their spending and expenses. I am running into an issue where the series and labels for apexchart are not updating after I push data from the plans into the arrays. I am not getting any error messages in the console so I was wondering if anyone knew what I was doing wrong here. here is the current code:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <p> <b>Your Plan: </b> {{plan.planName}}</p>
</div>
<div id="chart">
    <apexchart type="pie" width="380" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apexchart>
</div>
</template>


<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {

computed:{
plan(){
    let allPlans = this.$store.state.plans;

    let thisPlan = allPlans.find((aPlan)=>{return aPlan.planID == this.$route.params.pk});

    return thisPlan;
}
},

  data() {
   return {
                series: [],
                chartOptions: {
                    chart: {
                        width: 380,
                        type: "pie",
                        toolbar: {
                            show: true,
                        },
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Breakdown of Your Plan',
                        align: 'center',
                        style: {
                            color: '#000',
                        },
                    },
                    labels: [],
                    responsive: [
                        {
                            breakpoint: 480,
                            options: {
                                chart: {
                                    width: 250,
                                },
                                legend: {
                                    position: 'bottom',
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    legend: {
                        labels: {
                            colors: '#000',
                        },
                    },
                },
            }
  },

   mounted() {
    axios.get(`/plans/${this.$route.params.pk}/dashboard`).then((response) => {
        console.log("so heres the plan", response)
      for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        this.data.series.push(response.data[i].value);
        this.data.chartOptions.labels.push(response.data[i].key);
        }
    }).then(console.log("now heres the series", this.series))
  },
} 
 </script>
```

Comment: NOT YOUR ISSUE, but ...`.then(console.log("now heres the series", this.series))` won't work like you think it should ... though, because the console evaluates the content of objects when you inspect them, it probably looks like correct code to you ... but `.then` expect a function as an argument, which you have not done for the second `.then`

Comment: strange you don't get any errors though, since `this.data` is highly unlikely the correct place where `series` and `chartOptions` live ... they would be just `this.series` and `this.chartOptions` respectively - you really should be getting errors in the console - since `this.data.series` and `this.data.chartOptions` should be `undefined` - do any of your console.log's output anything?

Comment: Bravo, thank you for that colsole.log output, I fixed that. console.log("so heres the plan", response) prints out the correct data on the plan and console.log("now heres the series", results) now prints out undefined. here is the modified code to address your fixes.

Comment: mounted() {
    axios.get(`/plans/${this.$route.params.pk}/dashboard`).then((response) => {
  console.log("so heres the plan", response)
      for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        this.series.push(response.data[i].value);
        this.chartOptions.labels.push(response.data[i].key);
  }
    }).then((results) => {console.log("now heres the series", results)})
  },

Comment: `@Bravo` sorry I'm still getting familiar with stack overflow. My first console.log `console.log("so heres the plan", response)` returns the correct data that is stored on the backend that I am trying to push. `console.log("now heres the series", this.series)` was just returning `Proxy {}` to the console

Comment: correct, because that's how vue works - try `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.series))` if you want to see a vue `data` property without the proxy that makes it reactive